# Accessing return by pointer out of function

Tags: c++11

I have the following function

```
std::tuple<int,val*>Socket::recv(val* values ) // const
{
  char buf [ MAXRECV + 1 ];
  memset ( buf, 0, MAXRECV + 1 );

  int status = ::recv ( m_sock, buf, MAXRECV, 0 );

  if ( status == -1 )
  {
    std::cout << "status == -1   errno == " << errno << "  in Socket::recv\n";
    // return std::make_tuple(0,NULL);//this is not working
  }
  else if ( status == 0 )
  {
    //return std::make_tuple(0,NULL); //this is not working
  }
  else
  {
    struct val* values=(struct val*) buf;
    if(!std::isnan(values->val1) &&
       !std::isnan(values->val2) &&
       !std::isnan(values->val3) &&
       !std::isnan(values->val4),
       !std::isnan(values->val5),
       !std::isnan(values->val6))
       printf("received:%f %f %f %f %f %f\n", values->val1, values->val2,
         values->val3, values->val4, values->val5, values->val6);
      return std::make_tuple(status,values);
  }
}
```

The received values are printed out in to standard output correctly within the function.

But when I try to access these received values out of the function by calling as follows what I get is all 0's.[after creating Socket rcvd object]
Would you tell me how to access these values outside the function?

1.

```
std::cout << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)->val1)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)->val2)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)->val3)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)->val4)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)->val5)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)->val6)
          << std::endl;
```

2.

```
std::cout << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values).val1)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values).val2)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values).val3)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values).val4)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values).val5)
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values).val6)
          << std::endl;
```

3.

```
std::cout << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)[0])
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)[1])
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)[2])
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)[3])
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)[4])
          << std::get<1>(rcvd.recv(&values)[5])
          << std::endl;
```

where "values" comes from

```
struct val {
  val1;
  val2;
  val3;
  val4;
  val5;
  val6;} values;
```

All the three options of calling the function or access the struct val could not work for me.

Would you tell me

1. how to access these received values externally from any function?
2. how to return zero to struct pointer [NULL is not working ] when status is 0 or -1

Comment: Please edit your question and re-do the markup.

Comment: Please format your code somehow

Comment: I formatted your code, but for future please use a decent editor and code formatting. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure not all three ways you list even all compile, so that should say something. Not to mention you're returning a pointer to a memory block allocated in stack for the function, which is not available after returning.

Comment: Beside the fact that code won't work and you are lucky you are getting zeores, the specific syntax problem you have trouble with is that type deduction for tuple can't infer type by looking at returned value, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return std::make_tuple<int, val*>(0, nullptr);
```

The type of tuple is deduced from arguments, so by using `0,NULL` you are actually using the null constant wich is evaluted to 0 and hence deduced type is `<int,int>`.

By the way, I see no reason for using `NULL` in C++11, if you need that really for some reason then cast NULL to `val*`

```
static_cast<val*>(NULL);
```

EDIT:
Other viable alternatives are

```
val* nullval = nullptr;
return std::make_tuple(0, nullval);
```

Or

```
return std::make_tuple(0, static_cast<val*>(nullptr));
```

Or (as comment suggest)

```
return {0, nullptr};
```

Choose the one that seems more clear to you.

Comment: `std::make_tuple` is not meant to be called with explicitly specified type template arguments

Comment: make_tuple is used to deduce the types. Since the return type is already defined, 'return {0, nullptr};' is even better.

Comment: Nice suggestion John :). (There's the chance it is actually usefull for me too)

Answer (score -1):

You are lucky that the outside function is printing zeroes. It might have as well just dumped the core on you :)

What you are doing is accessing a buffer, that was created on a stack, after that stack was released (once the function's execution finished). That is HIGHLY UNSAFE and, pretty much, illegal.

Instead what you should do is allocate your data buffer in a 'free memory", using functions like `malloc` (in C) or operator `new/new[]` (in C++).

The quick fix is to replace the line

```
char buf [ MAXRECV + 1 ];
```

with

```
char * buf = new char [ MAXRECV + 1 ];
```

And when you do a type casting on line

```
struct val* values=(struct val*) buf;
```

you really ought to be sure that what you do is correct. If the `sizeof()` of you `struct val` is more than the `sizeof(char[MAXRECV + 1])` you'll get in memory access troubles.

After you are done using the returned data buffer don't forget to release it with a call to `free` (in C) or `delete/delete[]` (in C++). Otherwise you'd have what is called a memory leak.

Comment: After you are done writing your answer, don't forget to audit it for using incredibly unsafe language features that nobody should ever use.

Comment: The suggestions to return {0.nullptr} worked. But I still could not access the received values outside the function by using new/delete . Would any one help me with this? I wasted much time. My project dead line is approaching .

Comment: @Puppy - could you be so kind as to leave the sarcasm aside and let me know in direct language what is it you are talking about? Much appreciate your attention.

Comment: @YePhIcK : The received data is printed correctly inside function ,but still could not be retrieved externally by calling . Is there some detail missing ?

Comment: @tadElemeta - still talking in riddles :) While inside the function the `char buf []` *allocated on a stack* is, of course, still valid and accessible. Once the function exits that pointer is no longer valid. Could you  please tell me where is my logic failing me?

Comment: @YePhIcK : Thanks . It does not mean your logic failing .What I need is a solution to access these values (which are printed out inside function) externally by making them as one of return values for the function. I tried with your suggestion [if I understood ] ,but still not working.

Comment: Could you share the code that is calling this function? Specifically I'd like to see how you use the parameter to your function before and after the call (starting with the declaration and initialization of it).